# Elastic Search with Scroll and Slice with NEST to retrieve large volume data parallel

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch.net

I am writing NEST code to retrieve large volume of data from Elastic search.Right now I am using Scroll feature to fetch all records from cluster as synchronous way .
Below is the code snippet.

```
var response = elasticClient.Search<IndexType>(s => s                                 
                                    .Source(sf => sf
                                    .Includes(i => i
                                               .Fields(                                                          
                                                          f => f.DateTime
                                                      )
                                             )
                                            )
                                            .Scroll("1m") 
                                            .From(0)
                                            .Size(9999)
                                    .Query(q => q

                                         .DateRange(r => r
                                             .Field(f => f.DateTime)
                                             .GreaterThanOrEquals(new DateTime(2017, 01, 01))
                                             .LessThan(new DateTime(2017, 04, 01))
                                         )
                                         )                                               
                                          .Sort(q => q.Ascending(u => u.DateTime))
                                         );


            List<IndexType> allData = new List<IndexType>();                                         
            while (response.Documents.Any())
            {
                foreach (var document in response.Documents)
                {
                    allData.Add(document);
                }                    

                response = elasticClient.Scroll<RACType>("1m", response.ScrollId);
            }
```

Now instead of while loop (fetching 10000 record in batch till all documents fetched ), is there any mechanism to do this Asynchronously/parallel so that I don't have to wait for all iteration ?

Comment: NEST has a ScrollAll method you should take a look at

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, now I have doubts regarding ScrollAll parameters like, How can we decide no of slices (Any standard rule to decide this number as I have read some where the ideal no should be equivalent to no of shards) ?

Same goes for MaxDegreeOfParallelism() like how can I decide this number as well ?

Comment: Yes should not exceed no of shards and start with small number and increase until you don't see any performance increase